# How to align Angular Multiselect from the bottom

Tags: angularjs

I am looking for align the Angular Multiselect from the bottom.

Problem is activating that dropdown will display it beneath the clickable trigger, no matter where on the screen it is. If the trigger is at the very bottom of the page, when clicked the dropdown will increase the page height, and the user will have to scroll down again to see the rest of the dropdown

[code link](http://plnkr.co/edit/AuaPnrWy56RCqJNzFQvH?p=preview)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a dropup feature in bootstrap.

Referece: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns-dropup

Comment: yes i was seen the dropup but i should need the Dropdown/ Dropup as well in this case how could i do the code in Angular.
pls have a look this http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/
see the example two how it works in bootstrap i need same in angular.

Comment: Saw you link, you just need to include the the `bootstrap-select.min.css` and `bootstrap-select.min.js` then your good to go. You just need to follow their select element example. You could create a directive for that. :D